# A spinning charged particle in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Consider a particle of electric charge $q$ and mass $m$. Let it have magnetic moment ${\bf \mathfrak{m}}$ (so the particle spins around itself, but its size is negligible). I think that the equations of motion of this particle in a magnetic field ${\bf B}$ are
\begin{eqnarray}
m\overset{\cdot\cdot}{\bf r}=q\frac{\dot{{\bf r}}}{c}\times {\bf B(r)}+({\bf {\mathfrak{m}}}\cdot\nabla){\bf B(r)},\\
\dot{{\bf \mathfrak{m}}}=\frac{g}{2}{\bf B}\times {\bf \mathfrak{m}},
\end{eqnarray}
where $g$ is a gyromagnetic ratio.

**1) Is it something well known?** (I believe so.)

**2) Does there exist a Lagrangian for which this is the Euler-Lagrange equation?**

Remark. In a homogeneous magnetic field the second equation corresponds to the Larmor precession.

Comment: Should that be $\dot{\mathfrak{m}}$ rather than $\dot{\mathbf{m}}$ in the second equation?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Random thoughts, not a full answer:  the Lorentz force (without the spin terms) can be derived from the Lagrangian $L = \frac{m}{2} \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 - q \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is the vector potential. (That minus might be a plus, I can't recall exactly.)  The spin-precession equation is first-order, which suggests that if you want to derive it from a Lagrangian you'll need to write that Lagrangian in terms of some configuration variables $q_i$ such that $\mathfrak{m}$ is dependent on the $\dot{q}_i$ velocities (since E-L equations are typically second-order.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert In the Lagrangian it should be $+q\dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{A}$, i.e. with velocity, not position.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch:  You are, of course, correct.  I'll blame that error on a lack of coffee yesterday morning.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Seifert's idea is correct, but there is a little complication ahead. You can already see that a Lagrangian picture is not straightforward since your phase space is of dimension $9$ ($3$ for space, $3$ for momentum, $3$ for magnetic moment with a first order in time ODE). However, if you want a Lagrange perspective, you'll need to come up with a configuration space with half the dimension. It could work if you realise that $m$ is actually constrained to conserve magnitude, so you actually lose a DoF to only have an even number, $8$.

In this case, it's easiest to derive the classical theory from the Hamiltonian formalism. This is because it is easily motivated from quantum mechanics. In your case, you are interested in the [Pauli equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) which can be motivated as non relativistic limit of the full Dirac equation. Your phase space is $9$ dimensional with Poisson brackets:

\begin{align}
\{x_i,p_j\} &= \delta_{ij} \\
\{m_i,m_j\} &= \gamma\epsilon_{ijk}m_k
\end{align}

with the other brackets being zero and $\gamma$ the gyromagnetic ratio. Your equations of motion can be derived using the Hamiltonian:

$$
H = \frac{1}{2}(p-qA)^2-m\cdot B
$$

(setting the units s.t. mass is unity):

\begin{align}
\dot r_i &= p_i -qA_i \\
\dot p_i &= q(p_j-qA_j)\partial_iA_j+\partial_i (m\cdot B) \\
\dot m &= \gamma m\times B
\end{align}

You can check that $|m|$ is conserved (by Poisson bracket or your equations of motion) so the outlined  strategy works. All I need to do is to parametrize the $m$ sphere by a pair of conjugate variables so that the conversion to Lagrange is made easier.

A natural candidate is to take $p_\phi = \frac{m_z}{\gamma}$, a normalised component of $m$ along a direction and $\phi$ the angle of $m$ in its perpendicular plane. It's natural because you first think about spherical coordinates $\phi,\theta$, but since the area element is $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, you need to replace $\theta\to\cos\theta$ so that the coordinates are symplectic and the additional factor for units. In the following I will set $m=\gamma s$. You thus get:

$$
m = \gamma\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi \sqrt{s^2-q^2} \\
\sin\phi \sqrt{s^2-q^2} \\
q \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\{\phi,p_\phi\} = 1$$

Identifying $p_\phi$ as the conjugate momentum of $\phi$ (analogous to the $z$ component of angular momentum), rewriting the Hamiltonian with these new variables:

$$
H = \frac{1}{2}(p-qA)^2-\gamma\left((B_x\cos\phi+B_y\sin\phi)\sqrt{s^2-p_\phi^2}+ B_z p_\phi\right)
$$

I get:

\begin{align}
\dot \phi &= \gamma\left((B_x\cos\phi+B_y\sin\phi) \frac{p_\phi}{\sqrt{s^2-p_\phi^2}}-B_z\right) \\
L &= p\cdot r+p_\phi\phi-H \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\dot r^2+q\dot r\cdot A +\gamma(B_x\cos\phi+B_y\sin\phi)\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2-p_\phi^2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\dot r^2+q\dot r\cdot A +\gamma (B_x\cos\phi+B_y\sin\phi)\sqrt{\frac{\dot \phi +\gamma(B_x\cos\phi+B_y\sin\phi+B_z)}{\dot \phi+\gamma B_z}}
\end{align}

With this Lagrangian, you can recover the action and get a variational formulation, which was not obvious from the original Poisson structure of phase space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. How did you get the Poisson bracket $\{m_i,m_j\}=|m|\epsilon_{ijk}m_k$? (Also in fact my original motivation was to understand where the Pauli equation comes from. )

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake there. You can get it from quantum mechanics by converting the  anticommutator into a Poisson bracket. Otherwise, you can apply the same reasoning, saying $m=\gamma s$ with $s$ interpreted as an intrinsic angular momentum which gives by definition: $$\{s_i,s_j\}=\epsilon_{ijk}s_k$$

Comment: Btw check your equations of motion. For the first line, the nabla is contracted with the wrong vector (eg check Griffiths EM chapter 8.3) and for the second line check the sign and the definition of the gyromagnetic ratio.

Comment: I did not find chapter 8.3 in Griffiths book.

Comment: I have the 4th edition, it’s at the end of the one on magnetic fields that do not work

Comment: @MKO IIRC Chapter 8.3 was new in the fourth edition and did not exist in previous versions.

Comment: Or you can find the correct formula on wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole

Comment: @lpz: I understand your argument and how you got the Lagrangian. You got it in an indirect way via the quantum mechanics (Pauli's Hamiltonian). But did you really check that the Euler-Lagrange equations corresponding to this Lagrangian are those which are in my post?

Comment: Well the equations you wrote on your post aren’t correct, so you won’t obtain them. However, from the general equivalence between Hamilton’s and Lagrange’s formalism and  I am guaranteed to obtain the same equations of motion I wrote in the third equation set. But no I did not compute the Euler Lagrange from $L$